# Delete all items in a database except the last date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, mysql-8.0

I have a MySQL table that looks (very simplified) like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `logging` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `level` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL
);
```

I would like to delete all rows of a specific `level`, except the last one (`time` is most recent).

Is there a way to select all rows with `level` set to a specific value and then delete all rows except the latest one in one single SQL query? How would I start solving this problem?

(As I said, this is a very simplified table, so please don't try to discuss possible design problems of this table. I removed some columns. It is designed per [PSR-3 logging standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/) and I don't think there is an easy way to change that. What I want to solve is how I can select from a table and then delete all but some rows of the same table. I have only intermediate knowledge of MySQL.)

Thank you for pushing me in the right direction :)

Edit:

The Database version is /usr/sbin/mysqld Ver 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Comment: What's your DBMS version ..? Prior to 8 or 8+ ?

Comment: 8+

/usr/sbin/mysqld  Ver 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Comment: will it help to use rank() to assign rank to rows based on date, then delete when rank=1. SELECT
    val,
    RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY val
    ) my_rank
FROM
    table;

Comment: `time` is not unique. What if you have two rows with exactly same timestamp for the same level? And what is the primary key in your table?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel the primary key is (obviously) id. If two timestamps are the same one of them is left, the others are deleted. It's as I wrote a very simplified table design. The real design has an object and an action and for instance, the task is to delete all logs of object user action logged in to be deleted except the latest one. Barbaros Özhan's answer solves my issue I think. Testing...

Comment: Keys are an important part of the schema. It doesn't matter if your question is a simplified version of your problem - It should be complete. Also log tables tend to be huge. So knowing the indexes could also help. I would also probably use an AUTO_INCREMENT id column, to determine what is most recent.. then you don't have any issues with ties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function ( as using DB version 8+ ) :

```
DELETE lg FROM `logging` AS lg
 WHERE lg.`id` IN
      ( SELECT t.`id` 
          FROM
         (
          SELECT t.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `time` DESC) as rn
            FROM `logging` t
       --  WHERE `level` = @lvl -- optionally add this line to restrict for a spesific value of `level`
         ) t
         WHERE t.rn > 1
       )
```

to delete all of the rows except the last inserted one(considering `id` is your primary key column).

Comment: What is "test" supposed to be? The "logging" table or is it some kind of dynamic table?

Comment: well my mistake :), need to replace with `logging`

Comment: ```
DELETE FROM `logging` AS lg
WHERE lg.`id` IN (
 SELECT t.`id`
 FROM (
  SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `time` DESC) AS rn
  FROM `logging` AS t
        WHERE `level`="1"
 ) AS t
 WHERE t.rn > 1
)
```

does what I want... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(time) FROM logging WHERE level=some_level INTO @TIME_COUNT;
SET @TIME_COUNT = @TIME_COUNT-1;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'DELETE FROM logging WHERE level=some_level ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT ?;';
EXECUTE STMT USING @TIME_COUNT;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AUTO_INCREMENT `id` column - I would use it to determine the most recent entry. Here is one way doing that:

```
delete l
from (
  select l1.level, max(id) as id
  from logging l1
  where l1.level = @level
) m
join logging l
  on  l.level = m.level
  and l.id    < m.id
```

An index on `(level)` should give you good performance and will support the `MAX()` subquery as well as the JOIN.

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9LyzHN39cJbVLin3RHGUC1/0)

If you really need to use the `time` column, you can modify the query as follows:

```
delete l
from (
  select l1.level, l1.id
  from logging l1
  where l1.level = @level
  order by l1.time desc, l1.id desc
  limit 1
) m
join logging l
  on  l.level = m.level
  and l.id   <> m.id
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oXVbAXakmmwqEbfvGhRQrh/0)

Here you would want to have an index on `(level, time)`.